# Not getting current location with GPSProvider

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

i have written this code to find location coordinates, it works when i used network provider but i did not get any location with GPS provider, can u help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button sendlocationbtn;
TextView getlocation;

String lat = "";
String lon = "";
String ret = "";
String clickable = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    sendlocationbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendlocationbtn);
    getlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getlocation);

    getlocation();
    try {
        GetAddress(lat, lon);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    sendlocationbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendlocationbtn);
    sendlocationbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                GetAddress(lat, lon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            intentcaller();


        }
    });


}

public String GetAddress(String lat, String lon) throws IOException {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {

        System.out.println(lat);
        System.out.println(lon);

        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon), 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }

            ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            clickable = "https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lon;
            System.out.println(clickable);
            getlocation.setText(ret);
        } else {
            ret = "No Address returned!";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ret = "Can't get Address!..retrying";
        getlocation.setText(ret);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        getlocation();
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
    return ret;


}





public void intentcaller() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, clickable);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void getlocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            getlocation.setText("lat: " + lat + ", lon: " + lon);
            try {
                GetAddress(lat, lon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getlocation.setText(ret);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Log.d("Lattitude", "Enable");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Log.e("Lattitude", "disable");
        }

    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

   }


}
```

i have fine permission in menifest.

Comment: Why are you posting code for `GetAddress()` where your problem is only `getLocation()` ? Or more to the point: `onLocationChanged()`. Unclear what your problem really is.

Comment: `void getlocation()`. Bad function name. you do not get a location with it. Instead you create a location listener. Locations are available in  `onLocationChanged()`.Better: `createLocationListener()`.

Comment: this codes give lat and lon along with address but with LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER. i need to get accurate location using GPS_Provider and here is the problem, if i change to GPS_provider, i do not get any lat,lon and address.

Comment: You only will get a lat and lon in onLocationChanged(). Please do not confuse us with obtaining an address from a lat and lon as that is a complete different problem. And of course you will not get an address if you do not have a lat and lon.

Comment: Where are you moving with your Android device? You realise there mostly is no gps reception in buildings?

Comment: ok, so u means if i change Network provider with GPS it will work. And ignoring address method.

Comment: the location i m getting with this code and google maps are bit different and google maps is more accurate under same conditions of mobile, how can i achieve same level of accuracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126616/discussion-between-ankur-jain-and-greenapps).

Comment: You get a location from your gps chip. What do you mean with getting a location from google maps? Google maps does not give you a location to begin with.